# 'SelectedItem' method in TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView, which starts at 'To Do List' header, when you Expand that there is 'Audit' and 'Error' and then finally you Expand them their would be all different kinds of things that needs Auditing.

How do create a method for when someone clicks on something inside 'Audit'

```
private void MyTreeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

This method starts when you just click anywhere on the TreeView.

I want it so when I Expand 'To Do List' and also Expand 'Audit' or 'Error' the method doesn't start. I only want the method to activate when they click something inside 'Audit'.

EDIT:

[image]

The highlighted value is the one I want the method to trigger when clicked.

Comment: How are you populating your `TreeView`? An `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @DropTheTable No, a list.

Comment: Have you tried casting the `SelectedItem` and if it meets the critera to be in the Audit category (i.e is an Audit object) then do your logic.

Comment: @DropTheTable I was thinking that but if the application changes and they want to change the header under 'To Do List' then I would have to change the code? Also, I don't know how to code that, I'm fairly new.

Comment: I see your point about keeping your code robust. However this way should be fine as its not reliant on the header name, but the underlying class. Can you tell me what your collection is a `List` of? and I'll inlcude it in a proper answer, explaining how to determine what type the `SelectedItem` is.

Comment: @DropTheTable It is a list of tasks from a task table in a database. I have used a stored procedure to call the collection into a list of a virtual entity class - `List<cAuditTasksEntity>` being the type of list, called `_tasks`.

Comment: Ok thanks, one more thing. Is cAuditTaskEntity a parent class? Or is there a separate List to get the items from the Error node of the tree?

Comment: @DropTheTable Every table in the database has its own virtual entity class. The Error node will also be a type of task, so will come from the same table.

Comment: Completely a side note, but, unless ou trule despise your users, may I recommend a different color scheme?

Comment: @JDB yes I wanted to change the foreground to black on the fonts but because they are generated I don't know how I can change the foreground to black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the `SelectionChanged` handler, however I can't imagine it being in `MouseDown` would be any different for this:

```
// initialise entityTask here if needed outside of the scope of the try/catch
try
{
    cAuditTaskEntity entityTask = (cAuditTaskEntity)tvTasks.SelectedItem;

    ... your logic here ...
}
catch(InvalidCastException invEx)
{
    // do nothing here, another type of task has been selected, cErrorTaskEntity for example
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("something else went wrong!", ex);
}
```

If possible I would recommend an inheritance structure, this would prevent the need for a try/catch. As you could do a check on which child class is in use. This might not be possible here, but I'd recommend keeping it in mind for future projects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there is no definition of .SelectedItem for _tasks, as it is just a generic list of cAuditTaskEntity type.

Comment: Ah! My bad, I meant `tvTasks`, this is referring to your `TreeView`. In your case, replace `tvTasks` with the `Name` you provided for your tree in xaml. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this works. Firstly, with your `cAuditTaskEntity = null;` there is an error saying that `It is a type but used like a variable` and also when I debug the code, on the `MyTreeView.SelectedItem` you can see which one is selected but `entityTask` is returning `NULL`

Comment: Also, the method doesn't get activated until I click on anything but the writing. So when I click on the `Transaction` under `Audit` the method wont trigger.

Comment: Ah yes, assigning to `null` initially is incorrect and in face unnecessary. For the `SelectedItem` during debugging, what `Type` does the selecteditem appear as? I have updated the code to match the name of your treeview and removed first line, where I was initialising the object to null.

Comment: @user3110814 I have also changed my method of casting in my answer to force an `Exception` to be thrown in the event that the casting can't be done.

Comment: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem' to type 'DAL.cAuditTasksEntity'.` is the Exception I get.

Comment: SelectedItem appearsas an Object

Comment: I see, I would recommend using this code inside the `SelectionChanged` method. If this doesn't help I would recommend asking a new question, posting code showing the point which you are now at and explaining this Exception.

Comment: Yeah I changed the method and when I select the `Transaction` under `Audit` it activates the method, but has the exception, thanks for your help up to this point has helped me.